# List files in directory as menu options and then run that selected script

Tags: bash, macos, menu, terminal, environment-variables

First post here, and quite a newbie to using terminal. Sorry in advance for any fails.

I'm trying to list whatever .sh files are in a directory, so when i choose the file, it runs the file. The files are just .sh files that export environment variables so i can load a specific job im working on.

The thing is, if i copy the script and paste into terminal and run, it works.

But if i try to run the script through terminal. It works, but doesnt set the environment variables. Here's the script.

```
cd ~/nuke/pipeline/executables/

echo "-- JOB LIST --"

# set the prompt used by select, replacing "#?"
PS3="Use number to select a file or 'stop' to cancel: "

# allow the user to choose a file
select filename in *.sh
do
    # leave the loop if the user says 'stop'
    if [[ "$REPLY" == stop ]]; then break; fi

    # complain if no file was selected, and loop to ask again
    if [[ "$filename" == "" ]]
    then
        echo "'$REPLY' is not a valid number"
        continue
    fi

    # now we can use the selected file, trying to get it to run the shell script
    . $filename
    echo "Job Environment is $filename"

    # it'll ask for another unless we leave the loop
    break
done




#And here's whats in one of the .sh files
export DIR=/Users/darren/nuke/pipeline
export JOB=RnD
export SHOT=base
```

Comment: How are you invoking your script?  Unless you invoke it as `source script` or `. script`, it is going to run in a subshell and the effect of `. $filename` is lost.

Comment: shoudn't it be invoking through the . $filename ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is the sub shell.  As you may be aware, environment variables set in a sub shell don't propagate to the parent.

Let's call the script in your question as `menu.sh`.  It is calling other scripts based on user's choice, through this line:

```
. $filename
```

Looks like you are invoking your script as `menu.sh`.  That would run in a sub shell and the environment variables set through the above `. $filename` call are lost when it finishes.

To make it work properly, you need to invoke `menu.sh` as:

```
source /path/to/menu.sh
```

or

```
. /path/to/menu.sh
```

Comment: ok, so where exactly would i add this text line? I'm not that good at this yet.

Comment: When you said `when I run the script throught terminal`, what command did you use? I am suggesting that you use `source menu.sh`, assuming your script is named `menu.sh`.